# Object.keys in safari behaves differently

Tags: javascript, object, safari

Consider of adding values to object as below

```js
var obj ={};
obj["3"] = 10;
obj["2"] = 10;
obj["0"] = 10;
alert(Object.keys(obj));
```

In all browser except safari Object.keys returns like 0,2,3 where as in safari this returns as added order like 3,2,0

Is this known issue in safari (any specific version)

Comment: More of a general javascript issue in that objects don't have order. If you want Object.keys ordered you have to sort them

Comment: Object properties are unordered. Safari's behavior is correct.

Comment: @Robby Cornelissen and @charlietfl Yes object properties are unordered but this fact doesn't define how `Object.keys()` should work. In Chrome, IE and FF if the keys (properties) are positive integers `Object.keys()` or the `for in` loop lists the keys in a sorted fashion regardless in whatever order they had been defined. Time to time this functionality saves me from doing one extra sort so Safari should do the job according to the rest.

Comment: @Redu What? "Safari should do the job according to the rest"? Safari should obey the spec. Which it does. If you want to rely on unspecified behavior to avoid doing a sort, feel free to, but if your code does not behave as expected, the onus is on you, not on the browser.

Answer (score 2):

The only requirement is that it retains the same order as `for ... in`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

If it does not you should file it as a bug with Safari, otherwise it is meeting the spec.

Answer (score 0):

It is expected behaviour of js objects, that the properties are not ordered. If you need this kind of behavior, then you should use `Map`.

You can sort the keys according to your sort order and then generate a map from the sorted key value pairs. The map will guarantee you the correct order.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

> Although the keys of an ordinary Object are ordered now, they didn’t use to be, and the order is complex. As a result, it’s best not to rely on property order.
> The order was first defined for own properties only in ECMAScript 2015; ECMAScript 2020 defines order for inherited properties as well. See the OrdinaryOwnPropertyKeys and EnumerateObjectProperties abstract specification operations. But note that no single mechanism iterates all of an object’s properties; the various mechanisms each include different subsets of properties. (for-in includes only enumerable string-keyed properties; Object.keys includes only own, enumerable, string-keyed properties; Object.getOwnPropertyNames includes own, string-keyed properties even if non-enumerable; Object.getOwnPropertySymbols does the same for just Symbol-keyed properties, etc.)